# Disable confirm dialog when passing credentials

Tags: selenium, firefox

While executing on Selenium 3 FF50 as url http://user:password@url', I get confirmation pop up that appears several times, even if to confirm it.

Selenium Webdriver times out there. Setting in FF set to remember pwd, but trying manually opening FF and pass that url, keep getting this conf pop up.

Anybody have same issue or know turnaround it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch focus to alert and to accept it. Try something like this:

IAlert alert = driverLand.SwitchTo().Alert();

alert.Accept();